# Python : how to solve "The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator."

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers

I had the following problem : 
There is a bunch of .csv files I have to download from a web site, about 100 of them. Downloading each one requires 3-4 clicks and I had to renew the download about every 3-4 months or so. 
So I created a Python 3 script to do this for me, using *urllib.request.urlopen()*.

The problem was that, if the manual download works fine, when I used the script, the returned file, instead of being a .csv was an html file containing the message "The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator."
I tried using wget or curl in bash and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Add user-agent in headers of your request.
Your code will be like:

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com/filename.doc'
filename = url.split('/')[-1]
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers = user_agent)
open(f'dirrictory/{filename}', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why do you think that adding `user-agent` headers will solve the OPs issue?